# Storing an retrieving formatted DATETIME from mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql

First of sorry if this question has been asked before which i am almost sure it has but i can't find a post that fully answers my question on what i am looking to achieve lots of conflicting advice.

Here is my user flow for inserting data with my api.

Here is my table.

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
         `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
         `title` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
         `releaseDate` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
         `createdDate` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
         PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

post data to api.

```
# POST /v1/tests
? title=test
```

This will create my record with the createdDate current timestamp & releaseDate current timestamp.

Now I want to retrieve my data with a get api call with the dates formatted to ISO8601

```
// My test model just retrieves data for a row
function test_model_test($id){

    $query = $this->db->get_where('test', array('id' => $id)0);
    return ($query->num_rows() > 0) ? $query->row() : false;

}

 // Test api call to retrieve the data I need the date in ISO8601 format
function test_get(){

    $data = $this->test_model->test($this->get('id'));

    $response = array(
        'id' => $data->id,
        'title' => $data->title,
        'releaseDate' => $data->releaseDate->format(\DateTime::ISO8601)
    }

    $this->response([
        'status' => TRUE,
        'message' => 'Successful',
        'data' => $response
    ], REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);

}
```

When I run this I am getting the error.

```
Call to a member function format() on string /
```

Do I need to convert my dates from stings to date and then format?

I can use mysql to return the data in the currect format like this.

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT *, 
                DATE_FORMAT(releaseDate, "%Y-%m-%dT%TZ") AS releaseDateFormatted, 
                DATE_FORMAT(createdDate, "%Y-%m-%dT%TZ") AS createdDateFormatted,  
                FROM test 
                WHERE id = ' . $id . ' 
            ');
```

I am not sure the best way to do it there are probably many I figure if I just keep the mysql clean this will allow me to change the format within php for other formats if needed.

Would really appreciate any suggestions best practices etc?

Thanks

Update this works

```
$releaseDate = new DateTime($value->releaseDate);
$releaseDate->format(\DateTime::ISO8601);
```

Comment: What you're doing is fine.

Comment: Hi @FrankerZ which way? I am suggesting 2 different ways of formatting the dates one with MySQL and one with PHP I prefer the PHP way but I am not sure the best way to format the returned dates? Thanks

Comment: You should do the formatting in PHP - and of course you will have to first parse the date string to convert it into Date object and only then apply the formatting (which inevitably will return a String).

Comment: Thanks both i have update my answer with want i am doing ;)